# Cannot find node module after deleting yarn.lock/package-lock.json

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, node-modules, package-lock.json

I have encountered a weird issue where I get the following error, when I re-generate my lock file.

`Cannot find module" @mui/icons-material/Close imported from within one of my node_modules. Did you mean to import @mui/icons-material/Close.js.`

That is, after I remove node_modules, clean npm cache, delete lock file, install packages, the error occurs. The "@mui/icons-material" is already installed after this, so it is bewildering to me why it cannot find the module. I have tried with both yarn and npm.

**Everything works fine if I just keep the original lock file**. And I have checked that the package is only installed once.

**For context, I am using nextjs + react + typescript + node v16.19.1 + npm v9.5.0 + yarn v1.22.19**

This is the call Stack:

[image]

Comment: package.json? Full error?

Comment: are you using yarn to npm to install the packages?

Comment: @JBallin there are no errors in my package.json file. The error happens when I compile the app.

Comment: @Ayudh I have to install with both yarn and npm from a clean repo. Although to no avail.

Comment: why do you have to use both? why not just one ?

Comment: @Ayudh oh sorry, my bad! I meant to say, I tired using both one at a time. But still no luck

Comment: please post your package.json so we may reproduce it

Comment: @Ayudh I was able to finally resolve it, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found out it is caused by the `@solana/solana-wallet-adapter-material-ui` package in `package-lock.json`. If it gets updated it will complain, so I just need to have the version as is. It got updated to `v0.16.26`. I just needed it to stay at `v0.16.22`.

Comment: While it's great you figured this out, you need to post all necessary details when you ask a question - in this case - you should have posted your package.json.

Comment: @Ayudh you are right, you would probably be able to reproduce it if you had the same package.json. Will remember for the next time!